# Username/password not accepted when enabling basic authentication for React app on Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, create-react-app, basic-authentication

I am trying to enable basic authentication for a React app deployed to heroku, using the [create-react-app buildpack](https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack), which includes the [static buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static). I succeed in enabling basic authentication - I get a login prompt - but the username and password that I configured via config variables are not accepted.

This is my configuration:

`static.json`:

```
{
  "root": "build/",
  "routes": {
    "/**": "index.html"
  },
  "basic_auth": true
}
```

I set the config variables `BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME` and `BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD` in the heroku web ui. According to the [static buildpack documentation](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static#basic-authentication), this should lead to a `.htpasswd` file being created in the `app` directory during deployment.

In the console I see that the environment variables are set but I can see that no `.htpasswd` file was generated in the `/app` directory:

```
~ $ printenv
PWD=/app
NODE_ENV=development
NODE_HOME=/app/.heroku/node
HOME=/app
BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD=mypassword
BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME=myusername
[...]

~ $ ls -a
.                   .env.production  bin           package-lock.json
..                  .gitignore       build         package.json
.buildpacks         .heroku          config        public
.env.development    .profile.d       logs          src
README.md           node_modules     static.json
```

The deployment log file shows no errors or warnings:

```
[...]
=====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-inner-buildpack.git#v9.0.0
=====> Detected Framework: React.js (create-react-app)
       Using existing `static.json`
       Enabling runtime environment variables
=====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static.git
=====> Detected Framework: Static HTML
-----> Installed nginx 1.19.0 to /app/bin
Using release configuration from last framework (Static HTML).
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 81M
-----> Launching...
       Released v22
       https://myapp.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

What can I do to find out why the .htpasswd file is not generated? Or is there a better way to enable basic authentication (without storing username/password in the source code)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer myself [here](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static/pull/45#issuecomment-263385861):

"`BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD` must be a hash of your password. Use command `openssl passwd -apr1` to hash your password"